# Possible to only have 1 English dictionary instead of 30 in Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, dictionary

When I right click on a text field in `firefox` 22 and select "Language" from the pop-up menu, I have ~30 English dictionary variations.

I have not installed them since this is the default `firefox` (version 22) that came with my distribution (Fedora 17).

**Question**

Is it possible to remove all English expect for the "English (United Kingdom)"?

Comment: Which Firefox is this? Which distribution? Where do you see these dictionaries? Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: Using Firefox 22, Fedora Linux 17 (soon 19), when I right click and select Languages, because I only know two languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries in `firefox` are installed as extensions. You should be able to remove any you don't want by looking through the list of installed dictionaries in "Tools"=>"Add-ons"=>"Extensions".

Alternatively, you may be able to delete them directly from the extensions folder. In my case, the three non-English dictionaries I have installed all have a folder called `language@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org`. You can have a look at the ones you have installed with this command:

```
find ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/extensions/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*dictionaries*"
```

Or, if they are installed system-wide:

```
find /usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/ /opt/firefox/extensions/ \ 
 -maxdepth 1 -name "*dictionaries*"
```

Once you have located them, you should be able to remove the dictionary entry by simply deleting the folders in question. For example:

```
find ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/extensions/ -maxdepth 1 \
   -name "*dictionaries*" -delete
```

Comment: Incredible! It worked! My system is 64bit, so I had to `find /usr/ -name "*dictionaries*"` where the dictionaries turned out to be in `/usr/lib64/xulrunner/dictionaries`. It was interesting to learn that they are installed from `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/xulrunner/dictionaries/en_DK.aff` gives `hunspell-en-0.20110318-9.fc17.noarch`

Comment: To add insult to injury, all those annoyingly useless variations are just symlinks to  en_GB-large file! What the hell firefox?! And on my distro, dir was `/usr/lib/firefox/dictionaries`