# How to remove Firefox's US English dictionary?

Tags: firefox, language, ubuntu-18.04

I thought I had followed [all the correct steps to remove a dictionary from Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1048306) 62.0 (on Ubuntu 18.04).

Under about:addons I have only the British English dictionary.
[image]

(under the "Languages" tab I see English (GB) enabled and (CA) and (SA) Disabled, no mention of (US).

I've followed this advice to [look for the dictionary files on the disk](https://superuser.com/a/614427/240729), but found none.

And yet, when I'm typing, not only do I get US English spelling advice, but it defaults to it instead of British English. I can change it back for one tab, but I'd like to set it for the whole application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer for at least Ubuntu here, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/761598

Go to `/usr/share/hunspell` and delete the `.dic` and `.aff` file for the languages you do not want.

Comment: I don't have `en_US` in `/usr/share/hunspell`. I only have `en_GB` and `es_AR`. Looks like `en_US` is somehow built into Firefox?